# Enable/Disable site features from powershell

Tags: powershell, my-site, minimal-download-strategy

I need to activate the Team Collaboration Lists feature and deactivate the Minimal Download strategy in a user's blog and personal site. I am a farm admin, is that possible using powershell?

UPDATE:
Some features are not showing up in some sites. See the differences:
[image]

[image]

How can I enable the Team Collaboration Features in a particular site if this is not available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are farm-admin and you can use server-code. PowerShell can be used.

Use [`Enable-SPFeature`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/enable-spfeature?view=sharepoint-ps) or [`Disable-SPFeature`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/disable-spfeature?view=sharepoint-ps)

If you use [`Get-SPFeature`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/get-spfeature?view=sharepoint-ps) keep in mind, that (mostly) only enabled features are listed. The docs says:

> The Get-SPFeature cmdlet behaves differently at each scope, returning
>   the enabled Features at each level. If no scope is provided, all
>   installed Features are returned.

Comment: Great, thanks! I have an issue though. There are some site features, for example Team Collaboration Lists, that are not showing up in some particular users. I have uploaded some screenshots.

Comment: Please have a look at the documentation. I have updated the answer.